# Check for window width or height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check for window size by width or height. If I use '&&' it will only check if both width and height are low. How can this be changed so that if width is above 1280, but height is below 720 that it will display the message or vice-versa?

```
var width = $(document).width(), height = $(document).height();

    if ((width < 1280) || (height < 720)) { // display message if screen resolution is too low

        // display message

    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window` instead of `document`; 
Use `innerHeight/innerWidth` instead of `height/width`

```
var width = $(window).innerWidth(), height = $(window).innerHeight();

    if ((width > 1280) && (height < 720)) { // display message if screen resolution is too low

        // display message

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

*if width is above 1280, but height is below 720*

You will need:

```
 if ((width > 1280) && (height < 720)) { // display message if screen resolution is too low

    // display message

};
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> or vice-versa?

This question is not about jQuery or even JavaScript. It's about the use of `if` statements in procedural programming languages.

```
if(width > 1280 && height < 720)
{
    alert("big difference between width and height");
}
else if (width < 720 && height > 1280)
{
    alert("now this time and height is bigger!");
}
```

Of course you can merge the two conditions if you will do the same thing in both places.

```
if((width > 1280 && height < 720) || (width < 720 && height > 1280))
{
    alert("big difference between width and height");
}
```